# How do i get the cakephp server command for version 2.1.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-3.x

My present cake project is in version 2.1.2.
I want to have a `server` console command like version 3.x provides.
How do I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A cli is not needed

```
cd /path/to/your/app/webroot/
php -S localhost:8000
```

Is the equivalent of [all the 3.x server command does](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Shell/ServerShell.php#L131-L142).

### I want a cli anyway

Well, the cli is very simple. So all you'd need is to create a command that does the same thing, in principle:

```
// app/Console/Command/ServerShell.php
<?php
App::uses('AppShell', 'Console/Command');

class ServerShell extends AppShell
{

    public function main()
    {
        $command = sprintf(
            "php -S %s:%d -t %s %s",
            'localhost',
            8080,
            escapeshellarg(WWW_ROOT),
            escapeshellarg(WWW_ROOT . '/index.php')
        );
        system($command);        
    }
}
```

Note that this only works with version 5.4+ of php as [that's when the inbuilt webserver was introduced](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

Comment: when i am using the command php -S localhost:8080 -t app/webroot/ , I am getting the following error in the console -> http://localhost:8080/index.php/users/debug_kit/css/debug_toolbar.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) , http://localhost:8080/index.php/users/debug_kit/js/js_debug_toolbar.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The simplest solution is to [make those files exists](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html#increasing-performance-of-plugin-and-theme-assets) and not rely on CakePHP to serve them for you.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your folder try this:

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t ./app/webroot
```